# Animating SwiftUI views with GeometryEffect

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to animate a Rectangle View size change on device rotation. Try the buggy example:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct QuestionApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            PortraitLandscapeRotation()
        }
    }
}

struct PortraitLandscapeRotation: View {
    @State private var currentCanvasWidth: CGFloat = 0.0
    @State private var currentCanvasHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
    @State private var canvasScaleWidth: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State private var canvasScaleHeight: CGFloat = 1.0
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            Rectangle()
                .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(maxWidth: geo.size.width * 0.5)
                .border(Color.red, width: 2)
            
                .overlay {
                    GeometryReader { innerGeo in
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(Color.yellow.opacity(0.2))
                            //HERE:
                            .modifier(ScaleEffect(scaleX: canvasScaleWidth, scaleY: canvasScaleHeight))
                            .onAppear {
                                currentCanvasWidth = innerGeo.size.width
                                currentCanvasHeight = innerGeo.size.height
                                print("Default size is \(innerGeo.size.width) x \(innerGeo.size.height)")
                            }
                            .onChange(of: innerGeo.size) { newSize in
                                //HERE: 
                                withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 2.0)) {
                                    canvasScaleWidth = newSize.width / currentCanvasWidth
                                    canvasScaleHeight = newSize.height / currentCanvasHeight
                                    print("NEW scale is \(canvasScaleWidth)x\(canvasScaleHeight)")
                                }
                                currentCanvasWidth = newSize.width
                                currentCanvasHeight = newSize.height
                            }
                    }
                }
                .padding()
        }
    }
}

//And here:
struct ScaleEffect: GeometryEffect {
    var scaleX: CGFloat
    var scaleY: CGFloat

    var animatableData: AnimatablePair<CGFloat, CGFloat> {
        get { AnimatablePair(scaleX, scaleY) }
        set {
            scaleX = newValue.first
            scaleY = newValue.second
        }
    }
    
    func effectValue(size: CGSize) -> ProjectionTransform {
        print("Transforming to \(scaleX)x\(scaleY)")
        return ProjectionTransform(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleX, y: scaleY))
    }
}
```

I want a smooth animation of size change when the device rotates.

Everything should work, but I get a strange bug - the inner view adapts its size quickly and then does the transformation animation again. Which results in a double size change like this: [wrong size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dBnG.png)

I don't know how to approach it. I'm only learning. Should I use MatchedGeometryEffect instead? Or both ways are wrong? :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is probably too open ended for Stack Overflow. I would start with these tutorials from SwiftUI Labs: [Advanced SwiftUI Animations – Part 1](https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-animations-part1/) and [Advanced SwiftUI Animations – Part 2](https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-animations-part2/). They will give you a good understanding of how to use `GeometryEffect`.

Comment: Thank you, glad to be here! I've used exactly that tutorial to code my example above. My main problem is that the device rotation spoils the animation. If I apply the animation via a button (without rotating the device) - it works :(

Comment: If the device rotates, you have to stop the animation, and restart it. You can, though I have never tried it with a device rotation, pause and resume the animation after the rotation is complete. One thing to remember with animations, the new view already exists. The animation is essentially a movie that the OS makes to cover that jarring change. But the underlying new view is there, and that is the context that you are operating in.